# beautifulSoup, получить содержимое ссылки

Tags: python-3.x, bs4

Google-page при поиске инфы выдает ссылки на сайты, их html-address вроде этого

```
soup.select('.r a[href]')

result: []
```

Как получить ссылки на сайты? Нужно ли прописывать абсолютный путь до ссылок на страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Крч, я додумал, суть в кодировке классов, они как-то меняются если использовать bs4|requests, один и тот же класс просто написан по разному, спарсил всю страницу и посмотрел на ее синтаксис, нашел нужную ссылку, но обернута уже другим классом (тем же, но с другой кодировкой)